# .NET Core 3.1 IMemoryCache is empty when seeded from integration tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, memorycache

The question is regarding a Web API using `Entity Framework Core 3.1` and `IMemoryCache` because of complex searches. Example repository:

```cs
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public UserRepository(IMemoryCache cache, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<List<UserCacheModel>> GetAll()
    {
        List<User> users = _cache.Get<List<User>>("users");
        if (users != null)
        {
            return UserMapper.MapToCacheModelList(users);
        }
        return await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> Insert(User user)
    {
        // Add to database
        _dbContext.Users.Add(user);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Add to cache
        List<UserCacheModel> cachedUsers = _cache.Get<List<UserCacheModel>>("users");
        cachedUsers.Add(UserMapper.MapToCacheModel(user));
        }
    }
```

This is a very simple example, but it gives you a clear idea how it is being used. To do complex tests, there is a custom web application factory in the test project, which configure the webhost, DI and everything using the `Startup.cs`. Obviously the `DbContext` is removed from the DI and switched to a `In-Memory DB` with `EF Core 3.1`.

The issue is that I want to seed the in-app `Memory Cache` within this custom web app factory. It works fine, however when a test is trying to insert a user, it fails because
`List<UserCacheModel> cachedUsers = _cache.Get<List<UserCacheModel>>("users");` this line will be null. The `MemoryCache` seeded from the web app factory seems to be a different instance from the one being resolve in the `UserRepository` from the DI.

However if I manually resolve the `IMemoryCache` from the factory scope, I can see the data seeded on startup. `DbContext` is seeded correctly, everything works fine except this

Update:

Integration tests are run via the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` namespace by creating a custom implementation of `WebApplicationFactory`. This creates a web app just like when you debug your own `API` and therefore when you call an `ActionMethod` with a request that will save a user, the `IMemoryCache` is the in-app` cache of that newly created web app just like a docker container and is NOT the same as the one you resolve from the integration test code.

Well at least this is what I think now.

Any ideas what is the best way to get that in-app `cache` without creating a fake controller in your app just for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting up the cache after you create the WebApplicationFactory, like this:

```
var factory = new MyWebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
var queriesClient = factory.CreateClient();
using var scope = factory.Services.CreateScope();
var memCache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
memCache.Set("Key", Value);

using HttpResponseMessage response = await queriesClient.GetAsync(new Uri(requestUri));
```

This will set-up the cache directly in the factory scope, and it will be used now.